# Prove that there exists a open neighborhood $V$ of $L$ such that $f|_V$ is injective.

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

> Let $M,N$ be two smooth manifolds. $f: M\rightarrow N$ is an immersion. $L$ is closed in M and $f:L\rightarrow f(L)$ is a homeomorphism, implying $f(L)$ is closed in $N$. Prove that there exists a open neighborhood $V$ of $L$ such that $f|_V$ is injective.

I just learned the concept of immersion, submersion and embedding. I know that locally, an immersion is injective. Is this related to the problem? I also tried to use local charts to cover $L$ but have no idea how to continue.

Appreciate any help or hint!

Comment: Is this an exercise somewhere or stated as a lemma ? Are you sure you cannot assume compactness or sth similar?

Comment: $f(L)$ need not be closed in $N$. E. g., if $N=\mathbb R$, $M=N\setminus\{0\}$, $f(x)=x$ and $L=M$, $f(L)$ is not closed.